# Clojure - idiomatic way to do dynamically nested loops

Tags: python, clojure

This code is intended to basically loop through each letter in the supplied string and continue until z, then increment the prior letter and restart at a  (e.g. starts at "bde", next would be "bdf", ends at "zzz" - the same way a typical loop would work.)

I could of course do a nested for comprehension since this is only three levels, but if the levels are arbitrarily deep, the way I would traditionally approach that is by using recursion (as demonstrated below), in what basically amounts to a depth first search.

The problem with this approach is that any non-trivial sized input blows the stack (for example, "abcd"), and I can't think of a good way to do it without recursion.  A similar approach in Python (with some small differences like accumulating results in a mutable list), implemented below the clojure code doesn't hit the stack limit for input "abcd".

I tried using loop/recur but this construct doesn't seem to work from within a for macro as the call must suspend on the next loop iteration and is therefore not in tail position (at least I believe that is the reason).

What is the most idiomatic way to approach this type of problem?

```clj
;;; example using for macro
(defn gen-pw [pw r]
  (cond (empty? pw) r
        :else (flatten (for [x (range (int(first pw)) 123)]
                            (gen-pw (rest pw) (str r (char x)))))))


;;; example using map instead of for macro
(defn gen-pw [pw r]
  (cond (empty? pw) r
        :else (flatten (map #(gen-pw (rest pw) (str r (char %)))
                            (range (int(first pw)) 123))))) 

(gen-pw "bde" "")
```

```py
def gen_pw(pw,r='',final=[]):
    if not pw:
        final.append(r)
        return 
    for letter in range(ord(pw[0]),123):
        gen_pw(pw[1:],r + chr(letter))
    return final

print(gen_pw('abcd'))
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Is this procedure supposed to create a list of lexicographic successors to a given string, i.e. `("bde" "bdf" "bdg" ... "zzz")`?

Comment: Yes, that is the intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating a list that is tremendously over-nested by evaluating something like this:

```
(for [...]
  (for [...]
    (for [...]
      ...)))
```

And then trying to fix the accidental nesting with `flatten`, which of course has to walk recursively into your gigantic structure, and then explodes. Instead, generate a flat list to begin with. The easiest way to do this is simply to take your `map` version, replace `map` with `mapcat`, and remove the now-unnecessary `flatten`:

```clj
(defn gen-pw [pw r]
  (cond (empty? pw) [r]
        :else (mapcat #(gen-pw (rest pw) (str r (char %)))
                      (range (int(first pw)) 123))))
```

You'll also have to adjust the base case from `r` to `[r]`, as I did here: you're generating a *list* of valid passwords, not just one password, and so the return type should always be a list.

Comment: I actually did try mapcat previously but goofed on the [r] portion so I was getting individual characters - this is what I was missing.  That's the good news, the bad news is that it still blows the stack.

Comment: Oh, of course. Because `(mapcat (mapcat (mapcat ...` is a problem too, just a different kind of problem. *edit*: Actually, no, I disagree. `(count (gen-pw "aaaaa" ""))` returns 11881376 just fine, and there's no way you have ten million stack frames to play with.

Comment: hmm let me test this again on my machine - was using on online REPL since I wasn't near it, and it choked there.  Previously not even "abcd" would run.

Comment: Incidentally this will still run out of stack if the desired string length is very large: it consumes a number of stack frames that is linear in the length of the string. So if you wanted to generate passwords that are a thousand characters long, you'd run into trouble. The same is true of your Python version, of course.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use `cond` here instead of just `if`?

Comment: I just made the minimal change to the code in the question. `if` is clearly better (and better still is to build up results as they come up the stack, rather than passing partial results down the stack).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using `iterate`:

```
(defn transition [[text n]]
  (let [c (nth text n)
        nxt (if (= c \z) \z (-> c int inc char))
        nxt-str (str (subs text 0 n) nxt (subs text (inc n) (dec (count text))))]
    (if (= \z nxt)
      [nxt-str (inc n)]
      [nxt-str n])))

(defn ongoing? [[text n]]
  (not (every? #(= \z %) text)))

(->> (iterate transition ["zza" 2])
     (take-while ongoing?)
     (map first))
```

Note that for `["zza" 2]` the `\a` is in third position (hence 2) and for ["dzs" 0] the `\d` is in first position (hence 0).

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem statement as about computing a cartesian product, so I'm inclined to just recommend [the lazy mutual-recursion implementation of that](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/4c3d26eec2206e09b8b8c305bfed921966bce6f6/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.cljc#L208) found in [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics). Using it becomes something like:

```
(ns loops
  (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :refer [cartesian-product]]
            [clojure.string :refer [join]]))

(defn chars-from [start]
  (map char (range (int start) 123)))

(defn gen-pw [pw]
  (map join (apply cartesian-product (map chars-from pw))))

(gen-pw "bde")
;;=> ("bde" "bdf" "bdg" ... "bee" "bef" "beg" ...
```

Comment: Yep - this would be the counterpart to itertools.product - I like it.  Thank you for this addition.

Answer (score -1):

If you're reaching the recursion limit, make your process [iterative rather than recursive](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1).

You're right that when the recursive procedure call is part of a larger expression (that is, not in tail position), it will produce a recursive process. Therefore, make sure that the recursive call represents the entire value of the procedure.

```
(defn gen-pw [pw r]
  (let (s (successor pw))
    (if (nil? s)                ; (successor "zzz") is equal to nil
      r
      (gen-pw s (cons s r)))))  ; (successor "bfe") is equal to "bff"
```

Comment: This is a solution that would work well in scheme, but doesn't work in clojure because there's no automatic tail-call optimization. You could fix that by using `recur`, but your approach is still strict/eager, where a lazy solution would be much better.